# CSS - hovering over element affects multiple elements

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a menu that is floating right on the screen and when hovering over one of the elements it does what it has to do, the opacity is changing of the rest and only the hovered element is emphasized. But when hovering between the elements on the empty space, a small portion of the space in the middle changes opacity to all elements. If I hover over an element near the bottom or top of it and the spaces between all elements, it does what it should. I know it has something to do with the `<ul>` tag but don't know how to solve it.
Here is the code:
**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About</a></li>
    <li><a>Projects</a></li>
    <li><a>Services</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    float:right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    }
ul li {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #003560;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    transition: all ease .3s;
    }
ul:hover li {
    color: #0089F9;
    opacity: .1;
    transition: all ease .3s;
    }
ul li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 15px 55px;
    }
li {
    border: 2px solid #0089F9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Vc2ug/49/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float: left` instead of `display: inline`

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #003560;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    transition: all ease .3s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7w8w86my/1/

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Obviously I need to reconsider myself with the display and float properties. They are kind of unclear to me when put in combination.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul:hover li {
  transition: all ease .3s;
}
```

Remove opacity and color properties for and make `ul:hover li` as above. Actually it means when moves is on `ul` tag, apply following properties lo `li.` So, when you are placing between two list items, it is on `ul` and so it i applying `opacity` to all list items.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your `<ul>` some padding at bottom and top. Like this:

```
ul {
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/44k1wnnL) is a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the whitespace in the HTML between `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem that when you direct the cursor at space between li all ul becomes hovered. You need to change structure of html and to refuse use of ul or to add a small script. For example so: https://jsfiddle.net/trean/sxoxpz2e/2/ , https://jsfiddle.net/trean/sxoxpz2e/2/embedded/result/

```
$('.menu > ul > li').hover(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('li').addClass('unhover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('unhover');
 });
```

CSS:

```
.unhover {
    color: #0089F9;
    opacity: .1;
    transition: all ease .3s;
    }
```

I don't exclude that there are ways to do without jquery, but so far anything to mind doesn't come, except refusal of ul in favor of hierarchy div.

Comment: Thank you for this solution too. It is very good alternative to css programming. I tried to accept this answer too, but obviously only one option is allowed as an answer.